# Magento Module - Linux Vs Windows?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, development, windows

What are the things we should note , if the Development of Magento modules in WAMP environment and the Production is LAMP environment,

Whenever i deploy the modules in linux , i got the problems related to the case sensitive of file names.

Please notify some common best practices , to avoid server compatibility problems for magento modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the only thing you should pay attention to is not having class names with uppercase letters inside the class path.
This works on both:  `Namespace_Module_Model_Classname`.
This may fail on linux: `Namespace_Module_Model_ClassName`.

If you instantiate the class mentioned above as `Mage::getModel('module/classname')` it works on both Linux and Windows if you declare the class like the first option.
If you declare the class like the second option presented you should instantiate it `Mage::getModel('module/className')` to make sure it works on both OS. But you can easily make a mistake and not realize because on Windows it will work with `Mage::getModel('module/classname')`.

So the main idea is to avoid as much as possible uppercase letters inside the class names. Only at the beginning or right after an underscore.

Comment: Was going to answer the question. But this is a very good answer.